# Power rule integrals can't find information about this

Tags: calculus

There probably is some but I'm just not sure how to explain this or write it in english basically the power rule says that if I wanna integrate x^n it's just equal to x^(n+1)/n+1 now if I have something like (x+3)^3 can I still just do this? to make it (x+3)^4/4 even though this isn't really just a single x anymore? And what if it's something like (x^2+3x)^4 can I just say its equal to (x^2+3x)^5/5?

Comment: The example $x+3$ still works this way. You can see this by substituting $t=x+3$. But in the case $x^2+3x$ this does not work anymore because the derivate of $x^2+3x$ is no more linear.

Comment: So it is best not to memorize a "power rule", and instead rely on substitution.  So, for example, the integral of $2^x$ is **not** $2^{x+1}/(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be understood by using substitution. Simply put $t=x+3$, in which case $\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$, and so the integral reduces to $\int t^{3}\mathrm dt$, which can be handled by the power rule, as being $t^{4}/4+c$. Now, $t$ can be replaced back with $x+3$.

As for the other example, it does not work as is, since an extra term comes up when writing $\mathrm dt$. If $t=x^2+3x$, then $\mathrm dt=(2x+3)\mathrm dx$. But we cannot simply write $\mathrm dx$ from this relation, in terms of $t$ only. So, it must be expanded and correspondingly integrated.